# pyusb cannot find usb devices on windows

Tags: python, pyusb

pyusb doesnt find any usb devices.I tried several devices and copied/pasted the VID and PID. Has anyone an idea,what I am doing wrong? I get always an error message: NameError: name '_04F2' is not defined

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=_04F2, idProduct=_B449)
  if dev is None:
    raise ValueError('Device is not found')
```

Comment: what is `_04F2`?

Comment: maybe it should be string `"_04F2"` and `"_B449"` evetually it may need hex value `0x04F2` and `0xB449`. For Python your `_04F2` and `_B449` are names of variables, not values.

Answer (score 0):

For Python your `_04F2` and `_B449` mean names of variables, not values, so you could do

```
_04F2 = "Hello World"
print(_04F2)

for _B449 in range(10):
    print(_B449)
```

Probably you needs string `"_04F2"` and `"_B449"`

```
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor="_04F2", idProduct="_B449")
```

evetually hex value `0x04F2` and `0xB449`.

```
dev = usb.core.find(idVendor=0x04F2, idProduct=0xB449)
```